# typo3 crawler indexing content

Tags: search, typo3

I use typo3 7.6.10
I have crawler that index all pages and in search result are showed but crawler is not indexing the "content" of the page.

I have to write something in Configuration?

Comment: Specify which crawler exactly are you using and maybe add a source code of startpage or a link, so we can check if there is something wrong with your HTML.

Comment: I solved just a moment ago. I added the marker in html:  <!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin--> "content to index" <!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->

Comment: i solved partially. the page is indexed but in search result not appear

Comment: i have all pages but in results i have not pages of 4 level. why?? i have to specify the depth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/en/tutorials/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html) by Xavier Perseguers tells you everything you need to do to index pages and records with Indexed Search. It was made for an older version of TYPO3 (as you can see from the screenshots) but it should work for newer releases too.